# Gaussian integral asymptotics

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am trying to derive the asymptotics of
$$\int_{2\sqrt{m}}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}x^mdx$$ as $m\to\infty$ with no success. I tried integrating by parts, but could get no nice expression. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Laplace method?

Comment: @AntonioVargas: no, not really. Could you give some more details?

Comment: @AntonioVargas It doesn't look like the Laplace method because the integral boundaries are moving.

Comment: With $y := x^2/4 \implies \mathrm{d}x = x\mathrm{d}x/2$, substitute to arrive at
$\int_{2\sqrt{m}}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}x^m\mathrm{d}x = \int_{2\sqrt{m}}^\infty \frac{1}{2}e^{-y}y^{\frac{m+1}{2}}\mathrm{d}x$. Maybe this [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) can be approximated? The asymptotics of the Gamma function is well known.

Comment: @Turion, I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the change of variables $x = 2\sqrt{m} y$ then the integral becomes

$$
\int_{2\sqrt{m}}^\infty e^{-x^2/4} x^m\,dx = \left(2\sqrt{m}\right)^{m+1} \int_1^\infty \exp\left[m\left(\log(y)-y^2\right)\right]\,dy.
$$

Over the interval $[1,\infty)$ the exponent $\log(y)-y^2$ has a maximum at $y = 1$.  According to the Laplace method we may obtain an asymptotic for the integral by expanding the exponent in Taylor series around this point and using the first two terms.  So, since

$$
\log(y)-y^2 = -1 - (y-1) + O(y-1)^2,
$$

we replace $\log(y) - y^2$ with $-1-(y-1) = -y$ and find that

$$
\int_1^\infty \exp\left[m\left(\log(y)-y^2\right)\right]\,dy \sim \int_1^\infty \exp(-my)\,dy = m^{-1}e^{-m}
$$

as $m \to \infty$.  Thus

$$
\int_{2\sqrt{m}}^\infty e^{-x^2/4} x^m\,dx \sim \left(2\sqrt{m}\right)^{m+1} m^{-1} e^{-m} = 2 \left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^m m^{(m-1)/2}
$$

as $m \to \infty$.

Comment: The article about Laplace's method in Wiki says that the method works if the maximum is attained somewhere in the midlle of the interval. In this case it is the endpoint. Is there no problem because of that?

Comment: There's no problem, it's just not the particular version of the Laplace method described in the wiki article.  The proof of this case is very similar to the proof of the case when the maximum is attained on the interior of the interval.

Comment: The proof can be found in de Bruijn's *Asymptotic Methods in Analysis*, for example.